# Why having multiple back buffers is better for performance?

Tags: c++, directx, buffer

Explain something to me which I don't quite understand yet. I've read that having multiple back buffers in DirectX is better for performance.

It says that while the front buffer is being drawn onto the screen let's say you have already rendered everything into the back buffer and the back buffer is ready to go, but obviously you have to wait until the front-buffer is fully drawn to make sure tearing doesn't occurs. So instead of waiting it starts rendering into one more another back-buffer.

In my view of C++, the only thing that would happen is that you would have to allocate more memory for more back-buffers. 
So, again,

Why having multiple back buffers is better for performance?

Comment: Define performance?  FPS?  FPS per Gig of Ram?  Pixels per fortnight?  Awesomeness per Gpu?

Comment: I won't be able to say, I'm a beginner, i'm studying it.All that it says is : `How can adding additional back buffers get better performance? Well, let's say that every once in a while you finish rendering the back buffer and are ready to swap, but the screen hasn't yet finished drawing the contents of the front buffer. Swapping now would cause more tearing. So what happens instead is your program stops and waits for the screen to finish. You could, of course, be spending this valuable time preparing the next image, and having multiple back buffers allows your program to do just that.`

Comment: So I believe it's just the program performance?

Comment: Better for average performance, worse for latency.  Image a first person shooter game with say 4 back buffers, when the user clicks on the screen they will be 4 frames behind the game engine.

Comment: You mean the latency of inputs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, if you only have two buffers, one is being displayed, and one is being drawn to. Once the GPU is finished with the current back-buffer, it will have to wait until the back-buffer becomes the front-buffer before it can draw the next frame. Not a problem if you don't care about vsync, since you just swap when the back-buffer is done, and go on to use the old front-buffer as the back-buffer.

Now, imagine instead that we can only swap buffers at the exact vsync, so we don't get tearing during the swap. So we have a 60 fps vsync, or 16ms to draw the back-buffer. Imagine also that depending on a few things, sometimes it takes 14 ms and sometimes 19 ms to draw a frame. If it takes 19ms, we have to wait 13ms for until the NEXT 16 ms interval comes along, before the GPU can draw anything.

With three buffers, the GPU can start drawing a third frame immediately, even tho' we missed the time-slot, meaning we have another 13ms to complete that before we drop the frame-rate noticeably. So average frame-rate is higher.

Obviously, a drawback with N frame-buffers is that the Nth frame will have to be "ready to draw" N-1 frames before the current frame is displayed, or there won't be any benefit.

So, if the frame-rate is rather slow, the actual drawing appearing on the screen will be "N-1 frames old". Consider some REALLY slow drawing, where each frame takes half a second. If you fire the gun in your FPS game, with a 3 frame-buffer system, the shot will not actually appear until 1.5s (three frames later) after you fired it. Fortunately, FPS games usually don't run as slow as that... ;)

[It is worth noting, however, that "performance" is often a more complex number than "frames per second" - for example, GPU usage, power consumption and GPU usage are important factors to consider]

Comment: Ah so there aren't just pros but also cons. Wish I could give another +1 for stating that

Comment: The main con is latency. For touch based games in particular having the response be a few frames behind the input can be quite frustrating.